# How to convert a Vagrantfile to a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, vagrant

I'm trying to use the following Vagrantfile to make a Dockerfile for learning purposes. So far this is what I've come up with:

From Udacity: "Intro to Relational Databases", this is my Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "pg_config.sh"
  # config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty32"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5000, host: 5000
end
```

pg_config.sh:

```
apt-get -qqy update
apt-get -qqy install postgresql python-psycopg2
apt-get -qqy install python-flask python-sqlalchemy
apt-get -qqy install python-pip
pip install bleach
pip install oauth2client
pip install requests
pip install httplib2
pip install redis
pip install passlib
pip install itsdangerous
pip install flask-httpauth
su postgres -c 'createuser -dRS vagrant'
su vagrant -c 'createdb'
su vagrant -c 'createdb forum'
su vagrant -c 'psql forum -f /vagrant/forum/forum.sql'

vagrantTip="[35m[1mThe shared directory is located at /vagrant\nTo access your shared files: cd /vagrant(B[m"
echo -e $vagrantTip > /etc/motd

wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable
make
make install
```

---

This is my attempt at converting to a Dockerfile:

```
# Set the base image to Ubuntu
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Update the repository sources list
RUN apt-get update

# Add the packages
RUN \
    apt-get -qqy install postgresql python-psycopg2 && \
    apt-get -qqy install python-flask python-sqlalchemy && \
    apt-get -qqy install python-pip && \
    pip install bleach && \
    pip install oauth2client && \
    pip install requests && \
    pip install httplib2 && \
    pip install redis && \
    pip install passlib && \
    pip install itsdangerous && \
    pip install flask-httpauth && \
    su postgres -c 'createuser -dRS vagrant' && \
    su vagrant -c 'createdb' && \
    su vagrant -c 'createdb forum' && \
    su vagrant -c 'psql forum -f /vagrant/forum/forum.sql' && \
    vagrantTip="[35m[1mThe shared directory is located at /vagrant\nTo access your shared files: cd /vagrant(B[m" && \
    echo -e $vagrantTip > /etc/motd && \
    wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz && \
    tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz && \
    cd redis-stable && \
    make && \
    make install

# Expose the default port
EXPOSE 5000
```

After running

```
docker build -t fullstack-vm .
```

I received the following errors:

```
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin:
```

What needs to be corrected in the Dockerfile for this to run properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
```

to your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Thanks. This took me much further but now getting error: Adding user postgres to group ssl-cert
 
Creating config file /etc/logrotate.d/postgresql-common with new version
Building PostgreSQL dictionaries from installed myspell/hunspell packages...
Removing obsolete dictionary files:
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.

Comment: Please read [Why is DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive discouraged in Dockerfiles?](https://docs.docker.com/v1.6/faq/#why-is-debian_frontendnoninteractive-discouraged-in-dockerfiles) from the Docker FAQ

Comment: Link above is dead, here's the updated FAQ link: [Why is DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive discouraged in Dockerfiles?](https://docs.docker.com/engine/faq/#why-is-debian_frontendnoninteractive-discouraged-in-dockerfiles)